# Magento2 - How to add static country code in Phone Number input field?

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address

I have only one country in country dropdown and I want to add static country code in `Phone Number` field in shipping and billing address in checkout.

How Can I add this in checkout shipping and billing address?

[image]

**Question Updated:**

I want to add a div before phone number field to manage the static country code like this:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can show the value using below code in,

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="ProcessReferrerConfiguration" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{

    /**
     * Checkout LayoutProcessor after process plugin.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $processor
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $processor, $jsLayout)
    {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
        ['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['telephone']['value'] = '+91';
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it tested? because I am not able to get desired result

Comment: Try my updated answer..Remove checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: Not working , Please also review My updated question

Comment: My updated answer is working one. I have tested, but it will be displayed directly inside telephone number field and not in separate box.

Comment: I need in separate box So I set this with css before Phone number field

Comment: You got any fix for this ?